# Number of Multiplications in nested loops: Big O

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

```
if x:
    for i in range(a):
       for z in range(a):
          for k in range(z):
             for p in range(i):
                c = (i * z) + (k * p)
else:
    for i in range(a):
       for z in range(a):
          for k in range(z):
              c = (i * z) + (k * p)
```

Would this be O(n^4)? Also, how many multiplications would occur?

EDIT: updated the code. Also, since the lower bound captures the max number of steps a valid input will force, wouldn't big omega be n^4 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the complexity is still `O(n^4)`. To make things simple, here is the trick to rearrange your code

```
for i in range(a):
   for p in range(i):
       f(i, p)
```

where `f(i, p)` is

```
for z in range(a):
    for k in range(z):
        c = (i * z) + (k * p)
```

In the first part, `f(i, p)` has been executed for `O(n^2/2)` up to the largest order (because of the summation `sum_i (i^2)`, do the math yourself). Similarly, the `f(i, p)` has the complexity of `f(i, p)` which is again equal to `O(n^2/2)`.

So the combined resulting order is `O(n^4/4)`. and there is two multiplications for each operation, so number of multiplication is `O(n^4/2)`

Answer (score 0):

The following code would only be O(n<sup>4</sup>) if all the numbers `a`, `z`, and `i` were O(n).

```
for i in range(a):
   for z in range(a):
      for k in range(z):
         for p in range(i):
            c = (i * z) + (k * p)
```

As you've written it, all we know is that that code block is O(a<sup>2</sup>zi). Similarly, the total number of multiplications that would occur would be: 2a<sup>2</sup>zi. And, again, if `a`, `z`, and `i` are all O(n), the number of multiplications would be O(n<sup>4</sup>).

I'm not sure what you want to know about the second block of code.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Big-O gives the upper bound, so no input can take more steps than the upper bound, right? How can i express this upper bound as a function and show, say f(n) for upper bound, f(n) belongs in O(n^4)?